# Correcting for p-value for "frequentist" sampling methodology

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value, signal-processing, frequentist

I have a regression of the form:

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta_{1}*X_{1} + \beta_{2}*X_{2} + \epsilon
$$

There are a few subtleties, however, that cause me to suspect the p-values are artificially low.  First I transform both Y and X2 using first differences of log values:

$$Y(t) = ln(y[t]/y[t-252]) = ln(y[t]) - ln(y[t-252])
$$
and
$$X_{2}(t) = ln(x_{2}[t]) - ln(x_{2}[t-252])
$$

Then I run the regression for Y[1:756].  If I had merely run for Y[1,252,504,756] I would trust the t-stats... my sampling interval matches my difference "span".  However, I am more interested in the "rolling" regression for Y[1:756].  Here my sampling frequency is 252 times greater than my difference span.

I believe this partial resampling (or "oversampling" in the language of signal processing) provides a better estimates of the betas, though likely making the t-stats and p-values overly optimistic.

Can anyone suggest a better way to estimate the statistical significance of beta2 in this regression?  Alternately are there any suggestions on alternate methods to keep the potential benefits of "partial overlapping resampling" while obtaining useful p-values and t-stats for the betas?

Comment: I have subsequently been made aware of the Bonferroni correction method described as being "super paranoid", but useful.  As it was described to me I can simply use "floor(N/252)=3 separate regressions and then multiply the best p-value by 3."  Since I may someday wish to publish in a peer-reviewed academic journal the conservative approach seems wise.  The preliminary conclusions of my initial regression are surprising and potentially useful in the the world of international finance so this feedback is encouraging.